# get result from DialogFragment

Tags: android

hello  i am developing an app which have the ability to set date and time for events. for now i succeed to load the TimePicker but when i click OK the application crash and i don't understand why. there is 1 fragment that call to my TimePicker fragment and i would like to retrieve the results into  the caller fragment.

thank you.

the caller fragment:

```
    package com.example.matant.gpsportclient.Controllers;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DialogFragment;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Switch;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.matant.gpsportclient.R;
import com.example.matant.gpsportclient.Utilities.TimePicker;


public class CreateEventFragmentController extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener,TimePicker.OnCompleteListener {

    private Button btnStartdate,btnstartTime,btnendTime,btninviteUsers,btnEndDate,btnSave,btnCancel;
    private EditText addressEditText,maxParticipantsEdittext,minAgeEditText;
    private CheckBox privateEventCbox,reccuringEventCbox,specificAddressCbox;
    private Spinner sportSpinner,genderSpinner,radiusSpinner;


    public CreateEventFragmentController() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_create_event_fragment_controller, container, false);


        //initialize the widgets
        btnStartdate = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.buttonFromDate);
        btnstartTime = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.buttonFromTime);
        btnEndDate = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.buttonEndDate);
        btnendTime = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.buttonEndTime);
        btninviteUsers = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.buttonInviteUsers);
        btnSave = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.ButtonSave);
        btnCancel = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.ButtonCancel);





        maxParticipantsEdittext = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.editTextMaxPaticipants);
        minAgeEditText = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.editTextMinAge);
        addressEditText = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.editTextLocation);

        privateEventCbox = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxPrivateEvent);
        reccuringEventCbox = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxRecurring);
        specificAddressCbox = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxSpecifcAddress);

        sportSpinner = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.spinnerSports);
        genderSpinner = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.spinnerGender);
        radiusSpinner = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.spinnerRadius);



        //gender spinner
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> genderAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(v.getContext(), R.array.eventgender, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

        genderAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        genderSpinner.setAdapter(genderAdapter);

        genderSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });//gender spinner



        //Sport Spinner
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> sportAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(v.getContext(), R.array.kind_of_sport, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

        sportAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        sportSpinner.setAdapter(sportAdapter);

        sportSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });

        //Sport Spinner

        //Radius Spinner
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> radiusAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(v.getContext(), R.array.radius_range, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

        radiusAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        radiusSpinner.setAdapter(radiusAdapter);

        radiusSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
        //Radius Spinner



        addressEditText.setVisibility(v.GONE);
        btninviteUsers.setVisibility(v.GONE);


        //private event check box listener
        privateEventCbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(privateEventCbox.isChecked())
                    btninviteUsers.setVisibility(v.VISIBLE);
                else
                    btninviteUsers.setVisibility(v.GONE);

            }
        });//private event check box listener

        //create event from specific location check box listener
        specificAddressCbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(specificAddressCbox.isChecked())
                    addressEditText.setVisibility(v.VISIBLE);
                else
                    addressEditText.setVisibility(v.GONE);
            }
        });//create event from specific location check box listener

        btnstartTime.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnendTime.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnStartdate.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnEndDate.setOnClickListener(this);

        return v;
    }



    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();

    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()) {
            case R.id.buttonFromTime:
            {
                {
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putInt("Time", 1);
                    DialogFragment TP = new TimePicker();
                    TP.setArguments(bundle);
                    TP.show(getFragmentManager(),"TimePicker");
                }
            }
                break;
            case R.id.buttonEndTime:
                {
                    {
                        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                        bundle.putInt("Time",2);
                        DialogFragment TP = new TimePicker();
                        TP.setArguments(bundle);
                        TP.show(getFragmentManager(),"TimePicker");
                    }
                    break;
                }



        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete(String flag,String time) {

         switch(flag)
        {
            case "start_time":
                btnstartTime.setText(time);
                break;
            case "end_time":
                    btnendTime.setText(time);
                break;
        }

    }
}
```

TimePickerFragment:

```
    package com.example.matant.gpsportclient.Utilities;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.Calendar;

/**
 * Created by matant on 9/7/2015.
 */
public class TimePicker extends DialogFragment implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {
    public  interface OnCompleteListener {
        public  void onComplete(String flag,String time);
    }

    private int Time_Picker ;
     static final int START_TIME = 1;
     static final int END_TIME = 2;
    private OnCompleteListener mListener;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        try{
            mListener =  (OnCompleteListener) getTargetFragment();
        }catch (ClassCastException e)
        {
            Log.d("Class casting Error",e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstance){
        final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
        Log.d("Calendar",String.valueOf(hour)+":"+String.valueOf(minute));
        if(bundle!=null){
            Time_Picker = bundle.getInt("Time",1);
        }
        switch (Time_Picker)
        {
            case START_TIME: {
                Time_Picker = START_TIME;
                return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute, android.text.format.DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
            }
            case END_TIME:
            {
                Time_Picker = END_TIME;
                return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute, android.text.format.DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(android.widget.TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        Log.d("Calendar",String.valueOf(hourOfDay)+":"+String.valueOf(minute));
        String s ="";

        if(Time_Picker == START_TIME)
        {
             s = String.valueOf(hourOfDay)+":"+String.valueOf(minute);
            mListener.onComplete("start_time",s);
        }
        else
        {
            s = String.valueOf(hourOfDay)+":"+String.valueOf(minute);
            mListener.onComplete("end_time",s);

        }

    }


}
```

the error i get:`

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.example.matant.gpsportclient.Utilities.TimePicker$OnCompleteListener.onComplete(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
            at com.example.matant.gpsportclient.Utilities.TimePicker.onTimeSet(TimePicker.java:71)
```

Comment: You can also use hosting activity to communicate between fragments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to call `setTargetFragment` in order to use `getTargetFragment` successfully. In your case

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt("Time", 1);
DialogFragment TP = new TimePicker();
TP.setArguments(bundle);
TP.setTargetFragment(this, 0)
TP.show(getFragmentManager(),"TimePicker");
```

you can find the documentation [here][1]

[1]: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setTargetFragment(android.app.Fragment, int)